# functional approach to cpp

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to build some nested functions like so (reduced example):

```
// the actual functions come from particle physics and are extremely ugly 
double f(double x){
  return 2*x+1;
}
//in reality a numerical derivative term
double F(const std::function<double(double)>& f, double x){
  return f(x) - f(x+1);
}
// in reality another higher order numerical derivative
double G(const std::function<double(double)>& f, double x){
  return f(x) + f(x+1);
}
// in reality a function where the index is supposed to control the degree of derivatives of the function
double H(const std::function<double(double)>& f, double x, int switch){
  if(0 == switch){ 
    return G(f(x)); 
  } else {
    return F(f(x));
  }
}
```

this is the goal (2d for demonstration):

```
double sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<1;++i){
  for(int j=0; j<1;++j){
    sum += H(H(f,i),j); 
  }
}
```

**So two things:**

1. I want to use a function `H` to switch between `F` and `G` (my actual problem has 3 cases).
2. I would like to find a way/concept of calling `H(H(...)...)` the problem with that is the type of the function `f` which is the first argument of `H`, when I pass it a second time the type is no longer `double(double)` but `double(std::function<double(double)>,double(double),double)` or so...

Or in other terms:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkbmJ.gif (cannot post images, not enough rep)

Comment: I'm not sure if your F and G should return a double. Are they supposed to modify the passed `f` and generate another function?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't explicitly use `std::function`, but make your function argument templated instead, like

```
template <typename Arg>
double F(Arg const & f, double x){
  return f(x) - f(x+1);
}
```

This enables a lot more room to both optimization and genericity.

Secondly, turn all your functions into returning a lambda:

```
template <typename Arg>
auto F(Arg const & f){
  return [f](double x){ return f(x) - f(x+1); };
}

template <typename Arg>
auto G(Arg const & f){
  return [f](double x){ return f(x) + f(x+1); };
}

template <typename Arg>
std::function<double(double)> H(Arg const & f, int which){
  if(0 == which){ 
    return F(f);
  } else {
    return G(f);
  }
}
```

Note the `auto` return type: this is needed for returning lambdas to work.

Now you don't call `F(f,x)`, but rather `F` transforms `f` into it's derivative (or something else), which can be now applied to an `x`. These can now be used like

```
F(f)(0.1); // apply F(f) to x=0.1

F(F(G(f)))(0.5); // apply F(F(G(f))) to x=0.5

H(H(f,0),1)(4.2); // apply H(H(f,0),1) to x=4.2
```

Comment: Thank you!  It works! Only with -std=c++14 btw, because of the auto return type.

Comment: I don't get the second part to work. `return F(f)` gives me `error: no matching function for call to F`. I suppose this must also be a lambda. 
`return F(f)(x)` works. But how do I get this into another lambda? Or better: how do give different arguments to `F` and `f` when they both wrapped? Somewhat like `F(F(f),i)(f_args)(F_args)` ? Where `F_args` are the args of the inner F.

Comment: @Nhork Oh, my bad. Of course, `H` cannot have `auto` return type, since the return type depends on the `which` argument. We'll have to use `std::function` here. Also, names are screwed up: `F` means both the derivative functor and the template parameter. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a value for the inner `f` and `switch` (N.B. change that name, `switch` is a flow control construct), then you can partially apply `H` and then pass that to `H`

```
std::function<double(double)> partial_H(std::function<double(double)> f, int choice)
{
    return [f, choice](double x) { return H(f, x, choice); };
}
```

Comment: Thank you this also helped!